# Duality of Projective and Inductive Limit

Tags: category-theory

Could someone please explain to me in what sense the projective and inductive limits are "dual" to one another?

Comment: In the sense that projective limit in $C^op$ is the same as injective limit in $C$. This is the meaning of duality in category theory.

Comment: Would it be possible to give an answer without category theory? I'm not familiar with category theory, but didn't know where else to post this.

Comment: @IttayWeiss: Your exponent/superscript should be {op}.

Comment: @Ittay: Please give answers as answers, not as comments.

Comment: @kfriend: You will need category theory to answer a question about category theoretic notions. Of course you might only think about the category of groups, say, but then there will be no duality.